# Using group_by, nesting(), complete() and compute time interval over a huge data set in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I struggle on my data for a long time and I don't know how to solve my problem. I work on nutritional data, that can be faked by this data set:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Used for data generation
groupFunction <- function(cat){
  case_when(
  cat == "apple" ~ "food",
  cat == "bread" ~ "food",
  cat == "cheese" ~ "food",
  cat == "chocolate" ~ "candy",
  cat == "water" ~ "drink",
  cat == "tea" ~ "drink"
  )
}

# Generate the data

set.seed(0)

fakeData <- tibble(
  id = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10), rep("C", 10), rep("D", 10)),
  eaten_at = sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2020/01/01'), as.POSIXct('2020/01/05'), by="15 min"), 40),
  category = sample(rep(c("apple", "bread", "cheese", "chocolate", "water", "tea"), 10), 40),
  group = groupFunction(category), 
  amount = sample(10:100, 40)
)

# For every id, for each day, every hour and each category: sum the eaten amount, 
# and keep 0 eaten amount so it is encounted in the mean calculation in step 2!
# PROBLEM: we loose time intervals where a given id didn't eat anything, this will
# biais the mean calculation in step 2!
step1 <- fakeData %>%
  mutate(eaten_at_hour = hour(eaten_at)) %>%
  group_by(id, eaten_at, eaten_at_hour, category, group) %>%
  summarise(eaten_amount = sum(amount)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(nesting(id, eaten_at, eaten_at_hour), 
           nesting(category, group), 
           fill = list(eaten_amount = 0)) 

# For every id, mean over the days the eaten amount for every hour interval. 
# As before, keep 0 counts so it's encounted in the mean calculation in step 3!
step2 <- step1 %>%
  group_by(id, eaten_at_hour, category, group) %>%
  summarise(mean_per_id = mean(eaten_amount)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(nesting(id, eaten_at_hour),
           nesting(category, group),
           fill = list(mean_per_id = 0))

# Mean over all id 
step3 <- step2 %>%
  group_by(eaten_at_hour, category, group) %>%
  summarise(mean_for_all = mean(mean_per_id)) %>%
  ungroup() 

# Plot the data
ggplot(step3, aes(x=eaten_at_hour, y=category, color = mean_for_all, shape = group)) +
  geom_point( size = 3) + 
  scale_color_gradient(low="blue", high="red", "Mean eaten\namount [g]")
```

What I want to build is a plot with 1h time interval on the x axis and the different food categories on the y axis, with mean eaten amount for all ids for each X min period over 24h (i.e. time interval must be flexible). I would like a plot looking like this:

[image: Desired output]

My thought was to compute:

1. for every id,
2. for every day this id has eaten something,
3. for every time interval of X hour (even if the id didn't eat anything),
4. and for every food category:

**-> sum the eaten amount**

Then:

1. for each id,
2. for each category,
3. and for each 1 hour interval over the days of participation:

**-> average the eaten amount**

Then:

**-> average all id so that we get for each category and for each 1 hour interval of a 24h period, the mean eaten amount**

For this I use the group_by(), nesting() and complete() functions. But I have 3 problems:

1. I want to be able to set the desired time interval, it can be 15 min but also 2 hours. I didn't found any solutions to this yet.
2. I need to have all time intervals for all id even if they didn't eat anything (so amout = 0) because when I mean for the days or among ids, the mean would be biaised if I don't include the zero counts.
3. My actual data set includes about 100k rows, so I think that my way of doing it would not be the most appropriate in term of efficiency. Furthermore, I want to design a shiny app for this data where a user could set the time interval manually for example, that means the plot must be computed again and again (lot of work for a computer when the code is not efficient...)

I'm aware that my question is totally oriented towards a specific problem but since I'm really blocked I would highly appreciate any help/inputs/ideas on one or both of my question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "I use the group_by(), nesting() and complete() functions.". Could you share this code with us?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Dan. I added my code and tried to clarify my questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understood your problem, but here is a draft of an answer.

First, a tricky way to group on an interval is to floor the hour (using `lubridate::hour`) divided by the step, and then multiply the result by the step. Then, I grouped by the id, hour, and group to sum and then by only hour and group to compute the mean.

```
eaten_n_hours = 2
df = fakeData %>% 
    mutate(hour = floor(hour(eaten_at)/eaten_n_hours)*eaten_n_hours) %>% 
    group_by(id, hour, group) %>% 
    summarise(amount = sum(amount, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
    group_by(hour, group) %>%
    summarise(amount_m = mean(amount, na.rm=T),
              amount_sd = sd(amount, na.rm=T)) %>%
    identity()
```

Then, you can plot the whole thing like this:

```
breaks_hour = seq(min(df$hour), max(df$hour)+1, eaten_n_hours)
ggplot(df, aes(x=hour, y=amount_m, group=group, color=group, fill=group))+
    geom_col(position="dodge") +
    # geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=amount_m-amount_sd, ymax=amount_m+amount_sd), position="dodge") +
    scale_x_binned(breaks=breaks_hour)
```

[image: plot]

This is not the prettiest plot ever, but I'm not sure whether it is due to my ununderstanding of the problem or to the example `fakeData`.

#### EDIT

I'm not familiar with tiles, but you can try using `geom_tiles` this way. Also, using `scales::breaks_width` allow having a flexible time interval.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=hour, y=group, fill=amount_m))+
    geom_tile()+
    scale_x_binned(breaks=scales::breaks_width(3)) # try other values
```

Comment: Thanks for the intup. It helps but still my problems are not resolved: how to get flexible time interval, and how to keep 0 counts for the mean calculation.

Comment: @ludo I'm not familiar with tiles, I tried something but I'm afraid this won't be enough. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now my questions are more clear :)

Comment: And yep indeed tiles looks promising, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a way to do this (thanks @Dan Chaltiel), it's surely not perfect but I'll post it here so it can be useful to others/or for the discussion:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Used for data generation
groupFunction <- function(cat){
  case_when(
    cat == "apple" ~ "food",
    cat == "bread" ~ "food",
    cat == "cheese" ~ "food",
    cat == "chocolate" ~ "candy",
    cat == "water" ~ "drink",
    cat == "tea" ~ "drink"
  )
}

# Generate the data
set.seed(0)

fakeData <- tibble(
  id = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10), rep("C", 10), rep("D", 10)),
  eaten_at = sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2020/01/01 22:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2020/01/05'), by="17 min"), 40),
  category = sample(rep(c("apple", "bread", "cheese", "chocolate", "water", "tea"), 10), 40),
  group = groupFunction(category), 
  amount = sample(10:100, 40)
)

# Set time interval in minutes here (0-60 min only): 
set_time <- 60

# Generate time sequence for one day (1440 seconds), with the desired interval input. Then set it as factor. 
timeLevels <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2020-1-1 0:00"), by = paste(set_time, "min", sep = " "), length.out = 1440/set_time)
timeLevels <- paste(hour(timeLevels), minute(timeLevels), sep = ":")

# Calculate the means, keeping zero counts
toPlot <- fakeData %>%
  mutate(eaten_hour = floor_date(eaten_at, unit = paste(set_time, "min", sep = " ")), 
         eaten_hour = paste(hour(eaten_hour), minute(eaten_hour), sep = ":"),
         eaten_hour = factor(eaten_hour, levels = timeLevels),
         eaten_date = date(eaten_at)) %>%
  group_by(eaten_date, eaten_hour, category, group) %>%
  summarise(sum_amount = sum(amount)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(eaten_date, eaten_hour, nesting(category, group), fill = list(sum_amount = 0)) %>%
  group_by(eaten_hour, category, group) %>%
  summarise(mean_amount = mean(sum_amount)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# Plot the data
gg <- ggplot(toPlot, aes(x=eaten_hour, y=category, fill=mean_amount))
gg <- gg + geom_tile(color="white", size=0.1)
gg <- gg + coord_equal() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
gg <- gg + labs(x = "Time of the day", y = NULL, title = "Mean eaten quantity over one day", fill = "Mean amount [g]")
gg
```

Output looks like: 
[image: Output]

Still open on any inputs about how to improve my code!